Bash: variable unconsistant in for loop
I try to write a bash that compiles and executes multiple files. The compilation works but the execution crashes.
Here is the code:
#!/bin/bash

echo "Génération des executables"
for file in $(ls *_test.c)
do  
  echo "génération de ${file%.c}.exe"
  #gcc -o "${file%.c}.exe" -I$1 '$file' $1/examCIN.c
  gcc -o ${file%.c}.exe $file examCIN.c 
done

echo; echo "**************"
echo "Execution des tests"

for file in $(ls *_test.exe)
do  
  echo "execution de ./$file"
  $(./$file)
done

and here is the result of the execution  :
fafi_dev@fafi-UbuntuStudio:~/Documents/Professionnel/Cours_Fab/ISEN/Algo/2024-2025/Examens/CIN-U/machine/Sujet$ ./test.sh 
Génération des executables
génération de examCIN_BSTdelete_test.exe
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/cc4KKeHZ.o : dans la fonction « BSTdelete_test » :
examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c:(.text+0x4f4) : référence indéfinie vers « BSTdelete »
/usr/bin/ld : examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c:(.text+0x51d) : référence indéfinie vers « BSTdelete »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
génération de examCIN_BSTdequeue_test.exe
génération de examCIN_BSTenqueue_test.exe
génération de examCIN_BSTinsert_test.exe
génération de examCIN_BSTmin_test.exe
génération de examCIN_BSTprint_test.exe
génération de examCIN_BSTSearch_test.exe
génération de examCIN_initTreeNode_test.exe

**************
Execution des tests
execution de ./examCIN_BSTdequeue_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_BSTenqueue_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: Vérifiez : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_BSTinsert_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_BSTmin_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_BSTprint_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: vérifiez : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_BSTSearch_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c : commande introuvable
execution de ./examCIN_initTreeNode_test.exe
./test.sh: ligne 17: examCIN_BSTdelete_test.c : commande introuvable

Can anybody explain to me why the file to be executed is the .c file and not the .exe as for the echo?

you say "the compilation works", but very clearly your output starts with an error from the compiler that says compilation failed. So, solve one problem after the other, and  fix your compilation first.

Sidenote http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Also, for file in $(ls *_test.c) is a bit ……… strange? you probably simply meant for file in *_test.c, right?

Please paste your script at shellcheck.net and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Why are you using $(./$file)? That attempts to execute the output of $file as a command. If you want to just execute $file, use ./"$file" directly. Is the output of each exe just the name of a .c file maybe?

$(./$file) makes no sense, unless you want execute $file, then execute what that file printed? Did you ask ChatGPT or something to write this code? It really makes no sense.

yes I want execute the file compiled. In fact One of the compilation does not complete but it does not matter. I don't understand the second part : the echo prompt myfile.exe but the execution try to execute myfile.c.

you are doing more than just executing file. Please try to understand what $(./somefile) does as opposed to simply ./somefile. It's really not usual that people use a lot of constructs without understanding each of them!

@MarcusMüller : thanks for your advice. I will carea about better understanding the  constructions I use in particular $().

Try:
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob
info() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"; }
die() { info "$@"; exit 1; }

info 'Génération des executables'
for file in ./*_test.c; do
  exe=${file%.c}.exe
  info "génération de $exe"
  gcc -o "$exe" "$file" examCIN.c ||
    die "Aborting as $exe can't be compiled"
done

info '' '**************' 'Execution des tests'

for exe in ./*_test.exe; do  
  info "execution de $exe"
  "$exe" || die "Aborting as $exe failed"
done

You may also want to consider things like make to avoid recompiling software when the source hasn't changed.
Some notes:

$(ls *.c) doesn't make much sense. That's the shell finding the list of files whose name ends in .c and doesn't start with . in the current working directory and making one argument out of each to pass to ls. ls, taking that list of arguments, treating the ones starting with - as options and the rest as list of directories whose contents to list. For those files that are not of type directory (probably most here as it's rare for a directory to have its name end in .c), they're just printed as-is followed by a newline. Then with $(...), the output of ls is collected by the shell, split on characters of $IFS, then subject to further glob expansion to make up the list for will loop on.
$(./$file) makes even less sense. First, ./$file should have been "./$file" to prevent IFS-split+glob, then, you're collecting the output of the .exe command, applying split+glob on top and trying to execute the result as a command.
In bash like in the Bourne shell, if a glob does not match any file, it is left unexpanded. That's changed with the nullglob option which causes such globs to expand to nothing instead. An alternative is to use failglob which causes a failure instead, though handling those errors can sometimes be tricky.
To avoid files whose name starts with - to cause problems, we use ./*_test.c instead of *_test.c. For executable ones, the fact that the path contains a slash means $PATH look-up is not performed when invoked as "$exe".
As hinted already, the IFS-split+glob behaviour of $(...) mentioned above also applies to unquoted parameter expansions that are found in list context in bash, so it's important to quote all parameter expansions.
echo can generally not be used to output arbitrary data as is as depending on the shell and/or compile-time and/or runtime settings, it will not work properly for some strings starting with - or that contain backslashes.
It's customary for messages intended for the interactive user, as opposed to output which one may want to post-process, to go to stderr, even if they are not error messages like those informational messages here. Hence the printf>&2 (not echo as per above) in the info helper function.
When writing shell scripts, like for any other programming language, it's a good habit to stop and think what should happen if something fails. And also for your script to reflect in its exit status whether it has succeeded at its task or not. Here, we stop at the first compilation or .exe run error, but you may want to adapt the error handling strategy to your actual need.


Thanks for your help and the detailed answer. I will pay attention to it. This is helpfull for the understanding of bash.

www.tldp.org -> Bash guides - there are two of them, a bit old, but still worth a read - even just glancing through may help in understanding Bash.
